# Bash - How to get multi line text between XML tags

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, openwrt

I have a text file...

```
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<content>Pulsa:Rp200,Bonus:0 s&#x2F;d 12-JUL-17. 1GB Rp10rb.Mau?
1. Mau
2. Info
3. Internet
4. RAMADHAN HOTSALE
5. Nelpon
6. SMS
7. BB
8. NEW:UNLIMITED INTERNET
9. Roaming
10. 100MB2K</content>
</response>
```

and I want to extract the text between `<content>` up to `</content>`. I have tried:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<content> ).*?(?= </content>)' file
```

But it doesn't output anything, I want the end result to be like this:

```
Pulsa:Rp200,Bonus:0 s&#x2F;d 12-JUL-17. 1GB Rp10rb.Mau?
1. Mau
2. Info
3. Internet
4. RAMADHAN HOTSALE
5. Nelpon
6. SMS
7. BB
8. NEW:UNLIMITED INTERNET
9. Roaming
10. 100MB2K
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Uses the appropriate tool. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus sadly openwrt doesn't have tools like that, I use this on openwrt not on linux PC based distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep and Perl regular expression (`-P`):

```
grep -Poz '(?<=<content>)(.*\n)*.*(?=</content>)' file.xml
```

Output:

```
Pulsa:Rp200,Bonus:0 s/d 12-JUL-17. 1GB Rp10rb.Mau?
1. Mau
2. Info
3. Internet
4. RAMADHAN HOTSALE
5. Nelpon
6. SMS
7. BB
8. NEW:UNLIMITED INTERNET
9. Roaming
10. 100MB2K
```

Comment: Could you explain why it works in Perl mode but not regular regexes?

Comment: With Perl regular expression it is possible to remove head and tail with an expression (`<content>` and `</content>`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach:

```
tr \\n \\r < test.xml | sed 's:.*<content>\([^<]*\)<.*:\1:' | tr \\r \\n
```

Answer (score 0):

try with an awk solution too here.

```
awk '/<\/content>/{sub(/<\/content>/,"");print;A="";next} /<content>/{sub(/<content>/,"");A=1} A'   Input_file
```

Looking for string , if any line has that then substituting it with NULL and printing the current line, then making variable A's value to NULL. Mentioning next will skip all further statements.
Now looking for string  if any line has that then substitute the string with NULL and make a variable A with value 1 assign to it.

Now writing only variable A means it is a condition which will check if A's value is TRUE(NOT NULL) then it will print the current line.(A's value will be only TRUE when starting string  found and will be set to NULL when a close string  is found in any line).